# NSURLSession: Synchronous task hangs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, synchronous

I have recently replaced `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession` in my code.
As I am using many synchronous url-requests and `NSURLSession` doesn't support one, I used semaphores to make `NSURLSessionDataTask` synchronous.
I referred this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11519

I have a singleton 'Network Manger' with `NSURLSession` as a member variable. `NSURLSession` is instantiated only once and tasks are added to it.

But now synchronous request cause performance issues in my app. There are lags and app hangs when synchronous request is sent.

Her is the call to synchronous request:

```
NSURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSError *error;
id serverResponse=[[MyNetworkManager sharedInstance] synchronousDataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                            error:&error];
```

Everything works perfectly if I do not make `NetworkManager` as singleton and instantiate it everytime.

```
MyNetworkManager *manger=[[MyNetworkManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] responseSerializer:nil];
NSURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSError *error;
id *serverResponse=[manger synchronousDataTaskWithRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

Notes:

1.Exact Steps: There are total 3 (2 async and 1 sync ) `NSURLSessionDataTasks`. Second async task is called in completion handler of first task. Third synchronous task is called from completion handler of second. This third task is blocked forever and code doesn't proceed.

2.Everything is happening on background thread.

Why does synchronous data task work only if it is added to a new `NSURLSession`? Why it doesn't work if added to `NSURLSession` which has already executed two data tasks?

Comment: Consider to redesign your code using asynchronous tasks. There is always a way.

Comment: Thanks vadian but its a big, complex code and redesigning doesn't seem feasible. Is there any other way than redesigning?

Comment: Use GCD , add the Synchronous task & after getting response, do action on main thread.

Comment: You should better describe your problem, so that we can find a solution with an asynchronous approach. There's _always_ a way to describe any complex problem with an asynchronous approach. Trying to find an issue in your code which you didn't show and which is flawed by design makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the similar issue when I used to synchronus implementation using Semaphore and here is the cause of that issue :

I think that your an HTTP request is causing a redirection, and in the `willPerformHTTPRedirection` method, you haven't called the completionHandler for the new request. Try implementing the method as :

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
        newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"willPerformRedirection");
    completionHandler(request);

}
```